# How do I update a variable inputted to a function?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a function in my js file that will remove an item from an array and then save the new array to the variable. But here's the thing: I don't want it to only save ONE variable, I want it to save any array variable that I input. What I mean is something like this:

```
const list = [1,2,3];

function removeItem(array,index)
{
    let newArray = [];
    for(var i = 0 ; i < array.length ; i++)
    {
        if(i != index)
        {
            newArray.push(array[i]);
        }
    }
    array = newArray; // where it saves the variable
}

removeItem(list,0);
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're trying to do - but can you not just `return newArray` rather than trying to use an external variable? PS if so, what you have there can be more easily implemented using [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Comment: It is generally frowned upon to make changes to function parameters in the way you've demonstrated. Make a copy, make the changes to the copy of the array and return it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a prototype function, see this

```js
Array.prototype.removeItem = function(what) {
    if (this.indexOf(what) >= 0) this.splice(this.indexOf(what), 1);
}
var foo = [1, 2, 3];
foo.removeItem(2);
console.log(foo);
```

Answer (score 0):

You just want `arr.splice(i, 1);`

Comment: And why's that?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is probably to return the new array and let the calling code decide where to save it:

```
function removeItem(array, index) {
    let newArray = [];
    for(var i = 0 ; i < array.length ; i++) {
        if(i != index) {
            newArray.push(array[i]);
        }
    }
    return newArray;
}
```

And:

```
list = removeItem(list, 0);
```

This is probably ideal because modifying objects passed to a function as arguments is generally unexpected.  It's more common to return the new value.

If you want to modify the array *in place* then you'd need to only make edits to the `array` reference directly in the function and not use any kind of `newArray` copy.  Which could be as simple as:

```
function removeItem(array, index) {
    array.splice(index, 1);
}
```

And:

```
removeItem(list, 0);
```

But this could be very unintuitive since `list` is an argument to the function and you're not calling anything *on* `list` itself.  Contrast that to the syntax used in `splice` which is called on the array itself and implies that it may modify that array:

```
list.splice(0, 1);
```

(Though some array methods in JavaScript return a new array while others modify the array in place.  It's always best to refer to the documentation to make sure.)